# Make tabs align correctly

Tags: javascript, html, css

I’m trying to add tabs to a panel, but the tabs don't line up (align) with the boxes that are spawned from them. What I should do to correct this? Here is actual code: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bj8pd5op/32/). I am trying make a view like in the following screenshot:

[image: Screen]

```html
<main>
  <input id="tab1" type="radio" name="tabs" checked>
  <label for="tab1">Tab1</label>
  <input id="tab2" type="radio" name="tabs">
  <label for="tab2">Tab2</label>  
  <section id="content1"> 
    <form id="msform">
    <fieldset id="firstField">
        <h2 class="fs-title">Do yo have a fever?</h2>
        <input type="button" name="feveryes" class="next action-button" value="Yes" />
        <input type="button" name="feverno" class="next action-button" value="No" />
        <br><input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Reset" />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset id="feveryes">
        <h2 class="fs-title">Do you have a cough?</h2>
        <input type="button" name="coughyes" class="next action-button" value="Yes" />
        <input type="button" name="coughno" class="next action-button" value="No" />
        <br><input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Reset" />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset id="coughyes">
        <h2 class="fs-title">Go to Doctor!</h2>
        <br><input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Reset" />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset id="feverno">
        <h2 class="fs-title">You are healthy!</h2>
        <br><input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Reset" />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset id="coughno">
        <h2 class="fs-title">Be careful!</h2>
        <br><input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Reset" />
    </fieldset>  
</form>     
  </section>
<section id="content2">TEST TEST TEST
  </section>
</main>
```

Comment: try to clean up grammar and problem statement

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the padding from the section and margin from the form:

```
section {
  display: none;
  padding: 20px 0 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 0;
}


#msform fieldset {
    background: white;
    border: 0 none;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    padding: 20px 30px;

    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 80%;
    //margin: 0 10%;  // no margin

    /*stacking fieldsets above each other*/
    position: absolute;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2f6oovdd/

[image]

Comment: I`m still trying, so close but not enought, can help? :o

http://jsfiddle.net/bj8pd5op/33/

Comment: I'm not sure how exactly are you trying to make it